# How to display all the subsections' titles in navigation bar in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, themes

I want to modify miniframes theme in order to not display the bullets, but to show in the lower bar the titles of all the subsections of the current section. I did it modifying miniframe theme file: I eliminated `\insertnavigation` in the colorbox corresponding to sections and I inserted `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal` in the colorbox corresponding to subsections as follows:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center, ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex, leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
 \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
 \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal {\textwidth}{\hfill}{\hfill} 
 \end{beamercolorbox}%
```

It works correctly just if I have one section with subsections, while it is not able to recognize all the subsections if there are more than one sections with subsections. What should I do to display correctly the subsections titles?
I don't know if I was clear enough, but I hope you can help me!

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Where did you insert this code fragment? Which code did you eliminate where?